# springboot: no embedded datasource could be configured

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, tomcat, apache-netbeans

tengo este proyecto de springboot que no inicia por errores, lo estoy haciendo de un curso y segui unos tutoriales al pie de la letra pero me da este error y no se que tengo que corregir

Aca esta el codigo para que las puedan ver, gracias

Application.java:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class WpApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WpApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("persona") //localhost:8080/persona
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200") //se vincula con Angular en el front end
public class PersonaController {
    
    @Autowired // injecta la dependencia con cableado
    public PersonaService persoServ;
    
    
    
    @GetMapping("/lista")
    @ResponseBody
    public List <Persona> verPersonas(){
        return persoServ.verPersonas();
    }
    
    @GetMapping ("/ver/{id}")
    @ResponseBody
    public Persona verPersona(@PathVariable int id){
        return persoServ.buscarPersona(id);
    }
    
    //@PostMapping("/crear")
    public String agregarPersona (@RequestBody Persona pers){
        persoServ.crearPersona(pers);
        return "Persona creada";
    }
    
    @DeleteMapping("/borrar/{id}") 
    public String eliminarPersona(@PathVariable int id){
        persoServ.borrarPersona(id);
        return "Persona borrada";
    }
    
    @PutMapping("/editar")
    public void editarPersona(@RequestBody Persona pers){
        persoServ.editarPersona(pers);
    }
    
}
```

entity:

```
@Entity
public class Persona {
    
    // crear variables
    @Id // anotation id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY) //Incremento automatico de valor, identity esl la forma de incrementar
    private int id;
    
    //@NotNull //no es necesario
    //@Size(min =1,max=50,message="longitud incorrecta")
    private String nombres;
    private String apellido;
    
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE) //tipo dato fecha   jakarta.persistance.Temporaltype.DATE
    private Date fechaNac;
    
    @Lob // cambias el string a long para textos mas de 255 caracteres o @Size(min = 1 , max = 50, message = "no cumple con la longitud")
    private String sobreMi;
    private String urlImg;
    
    
    //constructor vacio
    public Persona() {
    }

    public Persona(int id, String nombres, String apellido, Date fechaNac, String sobreMi, String urlImg) {
        this.id = id;
        this.nombres = nombres;
        this.apellido = apellido;
        this.fechaNac = fechaNac;
        this.sobreMi = sobreMi;
        this.urlImg = urlImg;
    }
    
    
    
}
```

repository:

```
@Repository
public interface PersonaRepository extends JpaRepository <Persona, Integer>{ //extender de Jpa y Persona
    //metodos extras de JPA
}
```

service:

```
@Service //anotacion servicio
@Transactional //asistencia de datos
public class PersonaService {
    @Autowired 
    public PersonaRepository persoRepo;
    
    //@Override 
    public List<Persona> verPersonas(){
        List<Persona> listaPersonas=persoRepo.findAll(); //metodos JPA mostrar todo
        return listaPersonas;
    }
     
    
    public void crearPersona(Persona perso){
        persoRepo.save(perso);
    }
    
    public void editarPersona(Persona perso){
        persoRepo.save(perso);
    }
    
    public void borrarPersona(int id){
        persoRepo.deleteById(id);
    }
    
    public Persona buscarPersona(int id){
        Persona perso = persoRepo.findById(id).orElse(null); // si no encuentra la id devuelve null
        return perso;
    }
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.portfolio</groupId>
    <artifactId>wp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>wp</name>
    <description>backend proyecto argentinaprograma</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
                </dependency> 
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url= jdbc=mysql://localhost:3307/mydb?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

esto devuelve cuando le doy a run:

> 2023-04-06T01:34:27.698-03:00  INFO 5576 --- [  restartedMain]
> com.portfolio.wp.WpApplication           : Starting WpApplication
> using Java 17.0.5 with PID 5576
> (C:\Users\peter\OneDrive\Escritorio\YoProgramo3\wp\target\classes
> started by peter in C:\Users\peter\OneDrive\Escritorio\YoProgramo3\wp)

> 2023-04-06T01:34:27.704-03:00  INFO 5576 --- [  restartedMain]
> com.portfolio.wp.WpApplication           : No active profile set,
> falling back to 1 default profile: "default"

> 2023-04-06T01:34:27.788-03:00  INFO 5576 --- [  restartedMain]
> .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults
> active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable

> 2023-04-06T01:34:27.789-03:00  INFO 5576 --- [  restartedMain]
> .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related
> logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'

> 2023-04-06T01:34:28.712-03:00  INFO 5576 --- [  restartedMain]
> .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data
> JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode. 2023-04-06T01:34:28.801-03:00  INFO
> 5576 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate :
> Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 79 ms. Found 1 JPA
> repository interfaces. 2023-04-06T01:34:29.749-03:00  INFO 5576 --- [
> restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat
> initialized with port(s): 8080 (http) 2023-04-06T01:34:29.764-03:00
> INFO 5576 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService
> : Starting service [Tomcat] 2023-04-06T01:34:29.764-03:00  INFO 5576
> --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.5]

> 2023-04-06T01:34:29.866-03:00  INFO 5576 --- [  restartedMain]
> o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring
> embedded WebApplicationContext 2023-04-06T01:34:29.866-03:00  INFO
> 5576 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext :
> Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2075 ms

> 2023-04-06T01:34:29.922-03:00  INFO 5576 --- [  restartedMain]
> com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
> 2023-04-06T01:34:30.131-03:00  INFO 5576 --- [  restartedMain]
> o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing
> PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default] 2023-04-06T01:34:30.206-03:00
> INFO 5576 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version
> : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.1.7.Final

> 2023-04-06T01:34:30.630-03:00  INFO 5576 --- [  restartedMain]
> com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...

> 2023-04-06T01:34:30.631-03:00  WARN 5576 --- [  restartedMain]
> o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain
> connection to query metadata
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver org.h2.Driver claims to not accept
> jdbcUrl,
> jdbc=mysql://localhost:3307/mydb?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC  at
> com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.(DriverDataSource.java:110)
> ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]  at
>
> 2023-04-06T01:34:30.657-03:00  INFO 5576 --- [  restartedMain] SQL
> dialect                              : HHH000400: Using dialect:
> org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect 2023-04-06T01:34:30.659-03:00
> WARN 5576 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation
> : HHH90000026: MySQL8Dialect has been deprecated; use
> org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect instead

> 2023-04-06T01:34:31.425-03:00  INFO 5576 --- [  restartedMain]
> com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...

> 2023-04-06T01:34:31.439-03:00 ERROR 5576 --- [  restartedMain]
> j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Failed to initialize JPA
> EntityManagerFactory: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build
> Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver org.h2.Driver claims to not accept
> jdbcUrl,
> jdbc=mysql://localhost:3307/mydb?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC

> 2023-04-06T01:34:31.440-03:00  WARN 5576 --- [  restartedMain]
> ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered
> during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
> resource
> [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]:
> [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory;
> nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver org.h2.Driver
> claims to not accept jdbcUrl,
> jdbc=mysql://localhost:3307/mydb?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC

> 2023-04-06T01:34:31.442-03:00  INFO 5576 --- [  restartedMain]
> o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]

> 2023-04-06T01:34:31.453-03:00  INFO 5576 --- [  restartedMain]
> .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger :
>
> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation
> report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.

> 2023-04-06T01:34:31.471-03:00 ERROR 5576 --- [  restartedMain]
> o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
> resource
> [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]:
> [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory;
> nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver org.h2.Driver
> claims to not accept jdbcUrl,
> jdbc=mysql://localhost:3307/mydb?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver org.h2.Driver claims to
> not accept jdbcUrl,
> jdbc=mysql://localhost:3307/mydb?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
>
> ### ------------------------------------------------------------------------ BUILD SUCCESS
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ Total time:  6.437 s Finished at: 2023-04-06T01:34:31-03:00

Comment: Tienes el @entity en la entidad?la query del repositorio prueba a comentarla a ver si es que esta mal. y asi sin ver el reto del proyecto no se me ocurre mas

Comment: hola ya subilas imagenes del codigo, las @Entity estan todas no parecen ser el problema

Comment: no le veo nada raro. el@repository ya no es necesario en las ultimas versiones de spring

Comment: Hola wwwwww, bienvenido, la pregunta debe ser autocontenida, esto es que no dependa de imágenes o enlaces, por favor, edita tu pregunta elimina las imágenes, y agrega tu código y mensajes de error como texto, así evitarás recibir votos negativos y lograrás que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, gracias.

Comment: gracias marce, ahora lo corrijo

Comment: Tu application.properties  (.yaml si ocupas esa extensión) está bien configurado?, el error menciona que el DataSource tiene problemas y eso va en ese archivo. También el archivo pom.xml debe tener correcta la dependencia de la base de datos.

Answer (score 0):

Es error cuando no. Define correctamente el datasource , puede ser falta librería de spring-jpa o spring-jdbc, y el correspondiente driver. Por otro lado el application.properies/yaml puede definido el driver

El problema es este mismo
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57247240/spring-boot-jpa-mysql-failed-to-determine-a-suitable-driver-class , pero en post citado falta configurar la ubicación del server

Por último también dentro de las respuesta se cita como crear el Bean datasource